# How to fix the data, from a table in Microsoft Access (using SQL), not showing up on my TableView (fxml)?

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, javafx

I am just trying to see if I am able to get data from MS Access into a table using a TableView in FXML, but none of the data from my table in MS Access appears in the TableView. However, if I display just the content of my table as a message dialogue, all the correct information appears. Please can someone show me where I am going wrong.

I watched this Youtube video [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoiQVoNil9Q), and followed it step by step, as well as other sources, but nothing fixes my issue.

```
    @FXML
    private TableView<modelTable> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<modelTable, StringProperty> colStudentName;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<modelTable, StringProperty> colSurname;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<modelTable, IntegerProperty> colGrade;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<modelTable, StringProperty> colEmail;

    ObservableList<modelTable> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        try {
            Connection connection = DBConnect.getConnection();
            ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM data");

            while (rs.next()) {
//If I run the JOptionPane on its own, all the data is displayed
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (rs.getString("StudentName")+ "\t" + rs.getString("Surname") + "\t" + rs.getInt("Grade") + "\t" + rs.getString("Email")));
                list.add(new modelTable(rs.getString("StudentName"), rs.getString("Surname"), rs.getInt("Grade"), rs.getString("Email")));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TableController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        colStudentName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("StudentName"));
        colSurname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Surname"));
        colGrade.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Grade"));
        colEmail.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Email"));

        table.setItems(list);
    }

}
```

```
public class modelTable {

    private StringProperty colName, colSurname, colEmail;
    private IntegerProperty colGrade;

    public modelTable(String colName, String colSurname, int colGrade, String colEmail) {
        this.colName = new SimpleStringProperty(colName);
        this.colSurname = new SimpleStringProperty(colSurname);
        this.colEmail = new SimpleStringProperty(colEmail);
        this.colGrade = new SimpleIntegerProperty(colGrade);
    }

    public String getColName() {
        return colName.get();
    }

    public void setColName(String colName) {
        this.colName.set(colName);
    }

    public String getColSurname() {
        return colSurname.get();
    }

    public void setColSurname(String colSurname) {
        this.colSurname.set(colSurname);
    }

    public String getColEmail() {
        return colEmail.get();
    }

    public void setColEmail(String colEmail) {
        this.colEmail.set(colEmail);
    }

    public int getColGrade() {
        return colGrade.get();
    }

    public void setColGrade(int colGrade) {
        this.colGrade.set(colGrade);
    }

}
```

```
public class DBConnect {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C://Users//Huzaifah//Desktop//School work 2019//testing table.accdb");
        return connection;
    }
```

I expect the data to be in the TableView when I run the program, but it's empty. No error message is given, only an empty table.

I tried using this same database in just a simple program without a TableView and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your how you're setting your `CellValueFactory` for each column:

```
colStudentName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("StudentName"));
colSurname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Surname"));
colGrade.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Grade"));
colEmail.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Email"));
```

The properties you're specifying (`StudentName`, `Surname`, etc) do not match any exposed properties in your `modelTable` class.  In `modelTable`, all your properties begin with "col" for some reason.

> *As a side note, Java naming conventions suggest that class names begin with a capital letter...*

---

You should refactor your `ModelTable` class to use properties that are visible by your `TableView`. You should change your property names to be more reflective of the data. Adding a "col" prefix is confusing and unnecessary as your model class should not care or be aware of **how** it is going to be displayed:

```
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

class Scratch {

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty surname = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final IntegerProperty grade = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    public modelTable(String colName, String colSurname, int colGrade, String colEmail) {
        this.name.set(colName);
        this.surname.set(colSurname);
        this.email.set(colEmail);
        this.grade.set(colGrade);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname.get();
    }

    public StringProperty surnameProperty() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname.set(surname);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public StringProperty emailProperty() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email.set(email);
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty gradeProperty() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(int grade) {
        this.grade.set(grade);
    }
}
```

---

Note how we now declare the properties as final and initialize them as class fields. We can do this because we may change the *value* of a property, but will not change the property itself.

**Also notice** that we are adding a getter for each property. This allows us to refer to them directly in the controller when setting each `CellValueFactory`.

Then you need to update your `setCellValueFactory()` methods to use the new property names. I do not recommend using reflection (creating a new `PropertyValueFactory()`, however), as with your exposed properties, that is not necessary.

Instead, just pass a reference to the properties directly:

```
colStudentName.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().nameProperty());
colSurname.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().surnameProperty());
colEmail.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().emailProperty());
colGrade.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().gradeProperty());
```

Comment: Please can you clear this for me (I'm still a school going student), which properties in the code links to the TableView and which properties link to the column names in my MS Access table.

Comment: I recommend reading up on the MCV pattern in JavaFX. The column names in your Access database are not relevant to your `TableView`. Once you load the data from your database into the `ModelTable` objects, you will use those properties for the `TableView`.